# Using wp_handle_upload() to Direct Specific Path by Using $overrides

Tags: filters, uploads, hooks, array, wp-filesystem

How do you use `wp_handle_upload` function and `apply_filters` together to upload files on a specific path? What is going to be the override?

**For example:**

```
$overrides = array('file' => 'C:\\uploads\\filename.pdf','message' => 'File written');
apply_filter('wp_handle_upload',$overrides);
```

or something like that? Or is this the right code?

**The real question in here is: what `$overrides` can be used as the key to this associative array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a list of allowed mime types.

You could make it easy by just getting the allowed mime types like:

```
$file = $_FILES['the-file'];
$upload_file = wp_handle_upload($file, array(
    'test_form' => false,
    'mimes' => get_allowed_mime_types()
));
```

If you look at the codex for [Default allowed mime types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types#Default_allowed_mime_types), you could manually specify which ever mime types you want in that format.

An example would be like [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37249/9579).